# R Histogram With Density Curve and Translucent Area Curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a program I found that made a histogram shown in the attached picture. I am trying to make an identical one but with a different data set. However, I keep getting very strange results. The data represents how many MVP winners there were for each age category. Note you have to scroll to view more code.

Any help figuring out what the issue is would be greatly appreciated.

```
    df <- read.table(textConnection(
    'Age    Count
      20    2
      21    0
      22    2
      23    3
      24    6
      25    6
      26    9
      27    11
      28    7
      29    8
      30    6
      31    3
      32    2
      33    2
      34    1
      35    0
      36    2
      37    2
      38    1
      39    1'), header = TRUE)


    library(ggplot2)


    ggplot(df,aes(x=Age)) +
      geom_histogram()+
      labs(x="Age",
           y="Count",
           title="Age vs MLB MVP Count")


    ggplot(df,aes(x=Age)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth=2,
        fill="cornsilk",color="black")+
        labs(x="Age",
           y="Count",
           title="Age vs MLB MVP Count")


    ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,..density..)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth=2,
        fill="cornsilk",color="black")+
        labs(x="Age",
           y="Count",
           title="Age vs MLB MVP Count")



    histPlot <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,..density..))+ 
      geom_histogram(binwidth=2, fill="cornsilk",color="black")+  
      labs(x="Age",
           y="Count",
           title="Age vs MLB MVP Count")


    histPlot


    histPlot + geom_freqpoly(binwidth=2,color="red",size=1.2)


    histPlot + geom_line(stat="density",color="blue",size=1.2)+
      xlim(20,39)


    histPlot +
      geom_density(adjust=.4,fill="cyan",color="black",alpha=.40)+
      xlim(20,39)
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, meant to get rid of that. I will add what that was. I don't think so though.

Comment: I would just get basically a series of bars with the same height

Comment: To explain your strange results note that you are not using the Count information anywhere. Essentially you are creating one bar for each age without any y aesthetic - therefore, these are represented as just full (100%) bars. You could use the summarized data with something like `ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,y=Count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`. However, it will get fiendish when trying to use the density this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot's histogram feature typically is not meant for summarized data. A somewhat crude way to make your example work nicely is just to recreate the non-summarized data:

```
df = data.frame(Age=rep(df$Age, df$Count))
```

Then your graphs just go through. In practice you probably created the summaries yourself somehow so just skip summarizing and feed the raw data into ggplot.

Comment: That looks about right. Why does the y-axis go up to .2 when the highest count was 11 for 27 year old players?

Comment: I think you chose binwidth=2 at some point? that means you are grouping two adjacent ages

Comment: Just checked it - looks good when using binwidth=1 - max at 0.15

Comment: Oh, does the y-axis represent the probability of a player being that given age? Not the count? If so, is that the convention for this type of plot?

Comment: Best check the `geom_histogram` documentation (http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_histogram.html) - the standard histogram is relative frequency (count / total count), `geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..))` changes it to absolute frequency. Need to do it for both the histogram and the density (http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density.html).

Comment: Instead of a for loop, you can take advantage of vectorization: `dfnew = data.frame(Age=rep(df$Age, df$Count))`.

Comment: thanks @eipi10 - I had contemplated that I should not use the loop but struggled to find something that elegant. Updating my answer.